# Negative (minus sign) in the exponent

Tags: notation, exponentiation, number-comparison

After perusing a GRE quantitative comparison question, I noticed the following statement: Given $0 < a < b < 1$, the product of $a$ and $b$ is less than $b$. For this practice question, the examinee is only required to determine which of two columns (i.e., 'Column A' or 'Column B') is larger in value. Under 'Column A' was the quantity $a*b$ and under 'Column B' was the value $1$. The author of the tutorial then used the quantity $b^{-}$ underneath 'Column A' to denote a value of $b$ that is *less than* $a*b$. This was expressed for edification purposes.

I have never seen a variable superscripted with a hyphen or minus sign (only). Does it mean exactly as the author intended (i.e., the 'negative superscripted' quantity is *less than* another quantity)?

Is this appropriate convention in mathematics circles? A google search was unfruitful.

The question is a bit in the weeds, but my curiosity got the best of me.

Comment: This is not a standard notation.  Can you show its use in context?

Comment: Sure. But I should advise that this example was presented in a MagooshGRE video series on YouTube. Should I post a link to the video? If this is inappropriate I can explain it further in the comments. Thank you.

Comment: Explain it further, yes, but by editing the question and not through commenting.

Comment: Mathematics exams often invent new notation, then ask you to do something with it.  If you see strange notation on an exam, you should assume that it means exactly what the exam says it means *for the purposes of the exam*, but recognize that it might be nonsense outside of that exam room.

Comment: Thank you. I added some further context to the question. I'm sure the notation was ad hoc.